# How to contact two dataframes on axis 1 when row size is different

Tags: python, pandas

1st dataframe is this (`df1`):

```
Col1  Col2
abc   5
xyz   153
yyy   24
zzz   90
```

2nd dataframe is like this (`df2`):

```
col3  col
233   533
```

This is the output I want (Concat df2 on df1 on axis=1 on all rows):

```
Col1    Col2    col3    col
abc     5       233     533
xyz     153     233     533
yyy     24      233     533
zzz     90      233     533
```

But when I do `pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)`, I get this result:

```
Col1    Col2    col3    col
abc     5       233.0   533.0
xyz     153     NaN     NaN
yyy     24      NaN     NaN
zzz     90      NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform your second DataFrame as a dict and recreate a DataFrame before concatenating them:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, pd.DataFrame(df2.to_dict('list'), index=df1.index)], axis=1)
  Col1  Col2  col3  col
0  abc     5   233  533
1  xyz   153   233  533
2  yyy    24   233  533
3  zzz    90   233  533
```

Answer (score 2):

Perfect use case for a cross [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
```

Output:

```
  Col1  Col2  col3  col
0  abc     5   233  533
1  xyz   153   233  533
2  yyy    24   233  533
3  zzz    90   233  533
```

Comment: Works but Corralien's solution takes 32ms while your solution takes 65ms on my real df. The df1 shape is `548x2500` and df2 shape is `1x226` in my real  df.

Answer (score 2):

One fast method is [expand_grid](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.expand_grid.expand_grid) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn

others = {'df1':df1, 'df2':df2}

jn.expand_grid(others = others).droplevel(axis = 1, level = 0)

  Col1  Col2  col3  col
0  abc     5   233  533
1  xyz   153   233  533
2  yyy    24   233  533
3  zzz    90   233  533
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer seems to be 1ms faster than Corralien's solution on my real dataframe. But I would prefer using corralien's answer since it is simple and requires 1 less library.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
output = df1.join(df2).ffill()
```

Output:

```
  Col1  Col2   col3    col
0  abc     5  233.0  533.0
1  xyz   153  233.0  533.0
2  yyy    24  233.0  533.0
3  zzz    90  233.0  533.0
```